# Image Display using Javascript OOP

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to display the image in from a `<button>` but there seems to be some kind of problem.

I can't display the image. I've read some articles concerning about Javascript and OOP, I just don't know if I used them correctly as it is said.

Now going to my code, here what it looks like:

```
function myFunction() {
    function Image(src, height, width) {
        this.src = src;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }
    image.prototype.display = function () {
        document.body.appendChild(image);
    }
    var image = new Image("image.jpg", "200", "200");
    image.display();
}
}
```

Hope you help me out :)

Comment: Im not an expert. But should the top function be a class instead?

Comment: That function you mentioned is a function to be called from a button.

Comment: Try placing the inner function outside - like a sibling of the other one, i think the problem lies there

Comment: `Image` already exists as a constructor.

Comment: I tried it but nothing happens. Perhaps you could show me some code concerning this, so I could get a idea on how to do it correctly?

Comment: I don't think you can redefine the `Image` constructor...

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a DOM element and add the attributes to it. Here's a working example on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LADXL/

```
function myFunction() {

    function Image (src, height, width) {
        this.src = src;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }

    Image.prototype.display = function() {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.setAttribute("src", this.src);
            img.setAttribute("height", this.height);
            img.setAttribute("width", this.width);
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }

    var image = new Image ( "http://www.zwani.com/graphics/hello/images/10.gif", "200" , "200" );

    image.display();
}

myFunction();
```

Comment: Where you're wrong: you can't redefine `Image`'s constructor.
Where you're right: `Image.prototype.display` (sort of; prototyping existing API isn't considered kosher).

Comment: This works but I need a `FileReader()` for the `<input type=file>` and a submit button for it to work. Thank you for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Seens as you're defining your own `Image` class, you don't appear to be providing anything DOM-worthy to be rendered.

Your `display` method might look something a bit more like (note the capitalisation of `Image`):

```
Image.prototype.display = function() {
    // probably actually want to put this in the constructor
    // i.e., one img element per Image object
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src = this.src;
    image.style.height = this.height;
    image.style.width = this.width;
    // also probably don't want to append to body every time
    // display is called, style.display = "inline" or similar
    // would be better with a corresponding hide method
    document.body.appendChild(image);
}
```

Comment: I did something like this `function myFunction(src,height,width) {`
   `this.src = "image.jpg";`
   `this.height = 200;`
   `this.width = 200;`

  `Image.prototype.display = function() {`
       `var image = document.createElement("img");`
       `image.src = this.src;`
      `image.style.height = this.height;`
       `image.style.width = this.width;`
       `document.body.appendChild(image);`

   `}`

  `Image.display();`
 `}`
but I don't know if this was correct or not.

Comment: What is the point of `document.createElement("img");` when you can just do `new Image()`?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 none - if you're using the core `Image` class. The OP is using their own home-brewed `Image` class. For what purposes, I don't know.